# IBM Websphere Command Cache Invalidation

Tags: java, caching, command, websphere

My business flow is following:

1. Invalidate a command
2. Fetch data from command (database operations, little slower)

Step2 would be access by many concurrent users.

Now, when a command in invalidated, and user tries to fetch the data, multiple database queries starts executing because execute is little slower.

Is there any way to stop this multiple executions of queries?

> In other words, the question is: Can we make the execution of command,
>   and fetching data from command as Synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like this.

```
public class Fetcher {
  private static String data;
  private long timestamp;
  public synchronized String fetchData() {
    String result="";
    if (data!=null) {
     result=data;
     // let's invalidate too old data
     if (new Date().getTime()-timestamp> 100000)
      data=null;
    } else {
      DAO db = DAO.getConnection();
      data = db.performQuery();
      result=data;
    }
   return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Dynacache cacheable command and the queries are the same for users, then the command should get cached after the first execution.

Only the first execution should hit the database, after that the data should be fetched from cache until the cache is invalidated.

I usually use Dynacache as part of IBM Websphere Commerce suite.
Websphere Commerce uses a scheduled command to check a table called CACHEIVL.
You would setup triggers which would insert an invalidation id into CACHEIVL when the target table is changed.

Since you don't have the scheduled Dynacache command you can implement something specific to your use case using [Websphere schedulers](http://ibm.co/xQvIlt),

Here is an [example](http://ibm.co/z64IDM) of a cacheable command using Dynacache.